# Windows Scheduler doesn't execute Batch File or VBS

Tags: excel, windows, task, scheduled-tasks, job-scheduling

I am trying to  schedule a job to run either a batch file or a vbscript but it just stays on Running Status

Manually running the batch or vbscript works as intended but it doesn't once setup in task scheduler

**VBScript (excel.vbs)**

```
Set xlBook = GetObject("C:\MarvalDump\MarvalDump.xlsx")
xlBook.Save
```

**Batch (excel.bat)**

```
cscript //nologo C:\dump\excel.vbs
```

Running both scripts via Scheduler just creates an Excel process on Task Manager.

**PS.** I am using Windows Server 2012 R2  / Office 365 Pro Plus 2016 64-bit

Comment: Under which security context are your tasks scheduled to run?

Comment: im sorry, but i didn't understand the question. care to elaborate please.

Comment: [Task Security Context](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc722152.aspx).

Comment: It is under my username.

Comment: Sorry, that was the wrong question. It doesn't matter, which security context you used to run the scheduled task. What does matter is, that scheduled tasks run in Session 0. That's not an interactive session, and MS Office is specifically not supported to run in a non-interactive session (see [Help! My Scheduled Task does not run…](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/askperf/2015/02/18/help-my-scheduled-task-does-not-run/) and [Considerations for server-side Automation of Office](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/257757/considerations-for-server-side-automation-of-office)).